# One SharePoint calendar to display events from various Outlook calendars

Tags: sharepoint-online, calendar, sharepoint-calendar, outlook

hope you can help me. Here's the scenario: we have a few teams working within one project. Each team has their own shared calendar in Outlook. It happened in the past that some of the key stakeholders who needed to attend meetings didn't know about them, or meetings were scheduled for the same time.
So we would like to have one common SharePoint calendar aggregating events from a few separate Outlook shared calendars. I know you can create a SharePoint calendar but it is only picking events from a single Outlook calendar.
I did some searching but unfortunately haven't found a proper solution. All I found is how to feed events from one SharePoint calendar into another SharePoint calendar, but that's not what I'm looking for.
Any ideas?

Comment: you can no longer create [overlay calendars](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/overlay-a-sharepoint-calendar-with-a-calendar-from-exchange-or-sharepoint-4caebe59-3994-4a94-9322-b31abb8a5e9a) in one SharePoint calendars, not in modern SharePoint Online. We did this with Power Automate - prepare yourself for Graph API requests and tweaking correct URI as by the [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-list-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) it tends to skip some events without proper parameters limiting the date range to ~150days for example.